# Haskell line won't execute: do { n <- readLn ; print (n^2) }

Tags: linux, haskell

I've been following a [Learn Haskell in 10 Minutes](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Learn_Haskell_in_10_minutes) tutorial. Everything was going well until I reached this line:

```
do { n <- readLn ; print (n^2) }
```

It won't execute in ghci, and in Leksah I get the following error.

> Parse error: naked expression at top level

I've tried updating cabal and installing foo, but the problem continues.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: are you giving it the n value it needs?

Comment: I had no idea what the tutorial meant by "reading." Now I know. It wanted my input! Thank you for the help. I'm back on track now.

Comment: @SubtleArray: If an answer helped you, you should click the tick mark to accept it :)

Comment: To make it work in Leksah, make it `main = do { ... }`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not freezing, it's waiting for input. Try typing a number and pressing Enter.

Comment: Wow, what an oversight on my part. After I entered a number, it worked. Thank you.

Comment: It's not sleepin', it's restin'.